# Where do I put capacitor in my diode bridge AC to DC circuit?

Tags: capacitor, diodes, rectifier

I want to make a AC to DC converter, the seller give me these:

1. KBP307 diode bridge

   [image: 1. KBP307 diode bridge]
2. 2a104j capacitor

[image]

3. And a 470uF 50V capacitor.

---

All I can find on the internet only use one capacitor or two similar one, but that will double the voltage, which isn't what I want.

---

**How can I use both of those capacitor in my circuit?**

*Or if I should only use one then which?*

**Thanks!**

Comment: Draw the circuit and then we can tell if the arrangement is correct. (the built in circuit tool can be used) At this point I would be unwilling to give advice as it is difficult to know what you intend... To me there are 2 options.. but there are not enough components to complete either unless you don't mind failure modes that are potentially explosive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would connect the 2A104J (0.1 uF) capacitor and the 470 uF capacitor (watch polarity!!) to the DC output of the bridge rectifier.  The 470 uF capacitor will be polarized, so its positive terminal must be connected to the positive output terminal of the rectifier.

Adding multiple capacitors in parallel to the output of the recitfier will not double the voltage.